# AngularJS - $filter is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject a filter into my controller and use it as such:

```
angular
    .module('graduateCalculator', [])
        .filter('slug', function() {
                return function(input) {
                    if(input) {
                        return input.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z-]/g, '-');
                    }
                };
        }).controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$filter', app.graduateCalculator($filter)]);
```

However, I get the above error. I am obviously doing something very wrong - just not obvious enough to me.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $filter is not defined
```

It may have something to do with my function. It's written like so:

```
var app = {

    graduateCalculator: function($filter) {
        window.console.log( $filter('slug')('A random looking string...') );
    }

};
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to `[module].controller` is a constructor function, not calling the constructor function...

```
// change this...
.controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$filter', app.graduateCalculator($filter)]);
// to this...
.controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$filter', app.graduateCalculator]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You controller function (for which you currently have a function call, instead of a callback function) needs to be a function which takes $scope (controllers require $scope), also containing $filter.

```
controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){<your code here>}]);
```

There are, however, two ways to use your filter. You can either inject $filter and call

```
$filter('slug')(inputStuff)
```

or you can inject slugFilter and just call it directly

```
slugFilter(inputStuff)
```

One of the most common complaints about angular is the error messages, and this seems to be the problem here!

If I wasn't clear enough on anything let me know and I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 3):

I think error happen when you try to define a controller and inject `$filter` into your `app.graduateCalculator($filter)`.

With this way you invoke the function `app.graduateCalculator($filter)`. But the js interpreter didn't know what is `$filter`, so it threw the exception.

Just update your controller into this,

```
.controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$filter', app.graduateCalculator]);
```

And make sure your `graduateCalculator` have the parameter `$filter`.

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap your contorller with a function

```
angular.module('graduateCalculator', [])
    .filter('slug', function() {
            return function(input) {
                if(input) {
                    return input.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z-]/g, '-');
                }
            };
    })
    .controller('GraduateCalculatorController', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        app.graduateCalculator($filter)
    }]);
```

Comment: This appears to remove the error...but my app no longer works.

Comment: True true. It would distract from the original question for me to have gone into detail why it didn't work. But I appreciate your suggestion. It led me to the answer that this parameter should be a constructor function, not a function call.